# Decision Tree Based Form in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, infopath, decision-tree, infopath-forms-services

I have to implement solution for Microsoft Office SharePoint Server 2007 **Standard**. The user has some questions to be answered. Depending on answers, different results are presented. There will be max 5-6 questions for the longest path.

The question is - which tools/applications/technologies should I use to achieve it the easiest (fastest) way? My first thought was to use **MS InfoPath**, but there're server limitations - MOSS 2007 **Standard** does not provide **InfoPath Forms Services**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the Branching Logic capability of SahrePoint surveys. You can define what the next question will be based on the asnwer of the previous question.